# two dynamic dropdown code for one is working fine other is not. at a time one is working in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
        ///Code for source 
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement source=driver.findElement(By.id("fromCity"));
        source.sendKeys("mum");
        WebElement suggestion= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='From']"));
        suggestion.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        suggestion.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        ///Code for Destination

        WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.id("toCity"));
        destination.sendKeys("Pak");
        WebElement suggestion2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='To']"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        suggestion2.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        suggestion2.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Your description (i.e. title) is very confusing. Can you try to describe what the issue is in whole sentences in the body of your question? What works when used manually in a browser? What doesn't? What works when using Selenium, what doesn't?

Comment: i am trying to say at a time one is working if i comment first then second is fine same is the case with second one but both not working ?

Comment: Ok, so what does "not working" look like? What happens to the not working one? Does it simply not do anything or does it throw any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem here is that when you enter "source" from the dropdown and click on enter, the destination tabs get opened automatically.**

[image]

Now when you try to hit the below code:

```
WebElement destination = driver.findElement(By.id("toCity"));
destination.sendKeys("Pak");
```

It wouldn't run because another element is on the top of

`By.id("toCity"));` i.e `By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='To']")`

[image]

**I try to click on that and got the following error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input data-cy="toCity" id="toCity" type="text" class="fsw_inputField lineHeight36 latoBlack font30" readonly="" value="Bangalore"> is not clickable at point (480, 255). Other element would receive the click: 


<input type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="react-autowhatever-1" class="react-autosuggest__input react-autosuggest__input--open react-autosuggest__input--focused" placeholder="To" value="">
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.106)
```

**Corrected Code: As per the current scenarios**

///Code for Destination

```
        WebElement suggestion2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='To']"));
        suggestion2.sendKeys("Pak");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        suggestion2.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        suggestion2.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```