# Unable to identify Departure datepicker (for makemytrip website) using the Selenium code

Tags: java, selenium

I am doing a base test on the [www.makemytrip.com](http://www.makemytrip.com) web site and was looking to automate the date picker field. I am able to identify the `"Departure"` date field but same is throwing an exception on running the selenium web driver code and trying to click on the field.

Sharing across the `code`:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/Selenium/libs/Mar18/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
            
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.get("http://www.makemytrip.com");
            
//Locating calendar
WebElement dateCal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='font30 latoBlack']"));
            
dateCal.click();
```

Error that is being `thrown`:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span class="font30 latoBlack">...</span> is not clickable at point (816, 259). Other element would receive the click: <div data-cy="outsideModal" class="loginModal displayBlock modalLogin dynHeight personal "></div>
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', ip: 'xxx.xxx.x.xx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 92.0.4515.159, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 91.0.4472.19 (1bf021f248676..., userDataDir: C:\Users\XXXXX~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:65314}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: eb028e5d773c1cbd2fbbc8448a84a6e7
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at test.DatePicker.InvokeBrowser(DatePicker.java:80)
    at test.DemoDatePicker.main(DemoDatePicker.java:11)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68020311/5372079 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544732/how-to-select-date-from-makemytrip-having-two-months-in-popup

Comment: I even tried the following xpath for the destination date. Its working via inspect but failing in the selenium code //Locating destination calendar
  WebElement dateCal = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fsw_inputBox dates inactiveWidget activeWidget']"));

Comment: @RaviS : try out the solutions given below and let us know if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <span class="font30 latoBlack">...</span> is not clickable at point (816, 259). Other element would receive the click: <div data-cy="outsideModal" class="loginModal displayBlock modalLogin dynHeight personal "></div>
```

**basically implies that, the desire element is under the other elements.**

Basically when you open the mentioned web application, it automatically ask for login and date picker under the login pop up. the thing is you have to click on login button to let it disappear, then you can interact with date picker.

Also points to be noted here :

- use explicit waits for more stability of your scripts.
- try to use css over xpath, or probably id, class name, link text, tag name, if they are unique.

**Sample code :**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/Selenium/libs/Mar18/chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li[class$='userLoggedOut']"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("label[for='departure']"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey. The above code worked perfectly. I've just started learning selenium with java, so reaching out on these basic queries. Will definitely look to learn further on css

Comment: Out of curiosity, are their any communication channels related to on how date picker elements are to be handled in selenim java?

Comment: Those are web elements, we have to identify them uniquely. also you can google about locators, there are lot of topics. not sure if we have any communication channels.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the wait until functions, depends upon your case.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
By appct = By.xpath("//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(appct));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(appct)));
```